# convert wide table to long in R

Tags: r, data.table, melt, longtable

I have a dataset that look something like this:

```
groupA <- rbinom(n=50,size=1,prob=0.5)
groupB <- rbinom(n=50,size=1,prob=0.5)
groupC <- rbinom(n=50,size=1,prob=0.5)
groupD <- rbinom(n=50,size=1,prob=0.5)
dtTest <- cbind(groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD)
```

where 0 means "no" and 1 means "yes".

Now, i want to create a table with a column `Group` and another column `answer`, stating yes or no.

How can this be done ?

I tried the `melt` function and `data.table` group by, but keep getting error.

Comment: Tidyverse answer: `tibble(groupA, groupB, groupC, groupD) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "group", values_to = "answer") |> 
  mutate(answer = if_else(as.logical(answer), 'yes', 'no'))`

Answer (score 1):

Try tidyverse / tidyr:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
df <- dtTest %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "groups", values_to = "values") %>% 
  mutate(answer = ifelse(values == 0, "no", "yes" ))
```

Comment: Add `names_prefix = "group"` within `pviot_longer()` to be left with a single letter.

Answer (score 0):

We may use `stack` on the data.frame converted - `cbind` by default returns a matrix and not a data.frame.  Instead, we may directly use `data.frame(groupA, groupB, ...)`

```
out <- stack(as.data.frame(dtTest))[2:1]
names(out) <- c("Group", "answer")
out$answer <- c("no", "yes")[out$answer + 1]
```

-output

```
> head(out)
   Group answer
1 groupA     no
2 groupA     no
3 groupA    yes
4 groupA     no
5 groupA     no
6 groupA     no
```

---

For `data.table::melt`, we may specify the `measure` as the column names, (after converting to data.table - `as.data.table`)

```
library(data.table)
melt(as.data.table(dtTest), measure = colnames(dtTest), 
   variable.name = "Group", value.name = "answer")[, 
  answer := c("no", "yes")[answer + 1]][]
```

-output

```
   Group answer
  1: groupA     no
  2: groupA     no
  3: groupA    yes
  4: groupA     no
  5: groupA     no
 ---              
196: groupD    yes
197: groupD    yes
198: groupD    yes
199: groupD    yes
200: groupD     no
```